# RESTEasy - access to web folder for geting image

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, resteasy

I would like to allow users to access images saved in web folder.

For example - I have an image in web root folder "blank.png". But the link http://localhost:8080/myapp/blank.png returns 404 (not found).

Adding type to resteasy.media.type.mappings does not work.

I am a bit of a newbie in RESTEasy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your servlet mapping probably mapped all URLs to RESTeasy servlet, therefore overshadowing the normal static file serving. You should adjust servlet-mapping tags.

But you can also serve files from RESTeasy:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/img/{fileName}")
 public File getImage() { return new File("..."+fileName; }
```

Comment: I adjusted servlet-mappings (just *.xml).

Comment: This method is vulnerable to [Directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).